# How do I make a unique pointer that takes a class that takes a type? (Generic) It doesn't let me it

Tags: c++, generics

I was making my Node class for my Generic Binary Search Tree and I had my BSTNode class and BSTree class that had a unique pointer Root Node that took BSTNode of T.
Whenever I make the pointer it shows these errors
 • "unexpected token(s) preceding ';' "
  • "syntax error: missing ';' before '<' "
 • "missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int"
 How do I make the unique pointer with the node class of T?  By the way, I'm coding this in Visual Studios 2017.
 Binary Search Tree header file:

```
#include "BSTNode.h"

template <typename T>
class BST
{
public:
    BST();
    shared_ptr<BSTNode<T>> Root;
    void Insert(T newValue);
    void Delete(BSTNode<T> deleteNode);
    BSTNode<T> MinimumValue();
    BSTNode<T> MaximumValue();
    bool IsLeftChild();
    bool IsRightChild();    
    bool isEmpty();
};
```

Node header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class BSTNode
{
public:
    BSTNode(T);
    unique_ptr<T> Value;
    BSTNode* Parent;
    BSTNode* Right;
    BSTNode* Left;
};
```

Comment: Did you `#include` the header file that defines `Node` in the header file that defines `BST`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: yes I did include the header file. @RSahu

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and show which lines are flagged by the compiler. Posted code should not evoke any compiler messages.

Comment: @n.m. I will, this is my second post I'm knew to posting stuff on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add "using namespace std;" or use std:: when declaring your pointers?

This code compiles and runs (though it doesn't really do anything):

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class BSTNode
{
    public:
        BSTNode(T) {}
        std::unique_ptr<T> Value;
        BSTNode* Parent;
        BSTNode* Right;
        BSTNode* Left;
}; 

template <typename T>
class BST
{
    public:
        BST() {}
        shared_ptr<BSTNode<T>> Root;
        //void Insert(T newValue);
        //void Delete(TNode<T> deleteNode);
        //<T> MinimumValue();
        //TNode<T> MaximumValue();
        //bool IsLeftChild();
        //bool IsRightChild();
        //bool isEmpty();
}; 

int main()
{
    BST<int> bst;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to add using namepsace std. Should I make the parent,right,left a unique pointer?

Comment: I would say no especially If you plan on doing anything that manipulates the tree (moves nodes around) after the initial insertions like deletions, re-balancing, etc.

Comment: should I use a shared one or a raw one? @Marker

Comment: @Person • You could make Parent a weak_ptr, and Right and Left a shared_ptr.  But don't make Parent a shared_ptr, because then the mesh of objects would keep itself alive instead of straight-forwardly destructing properly.

Comment: I have always used raw pointers in data structures, though I think the shared_ptr makes sense for the Value.  I usually make the Node a private class so I don't have to worry about anything external causing pointer problems.   FWIW, with the data structures that are now part of C++, C#, Qt, etc. I haven't written any complex data structures in some time.